# jQuery.mobile.splitview popup positioning

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am using the splitview plugin of jQuery.mobile [jQuery Mobile - Splitview](https://github.com/asyraf9/jquerymobile-splitview) . I am using jQuery.mobile popups as context menus which are fired on taphold event.  Right now I am opening popus by

```
$("#myPopup").click();
```

where myPopup is popup defined in HTML.

In this way I can open popup, but I can not position the popup to the position of tap. Does anyone have an idea?

Something like

```
$( ".selector" ).popup( "open", {x:event.pageX, y: event.pageY} );
```

does not work because of splitview plugin. Without this plugin it works perfectly.

(and of coarse, I know, that taphold event does not contain information about position, that was just an example. I tried it also with pure numbers and it does not work either)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my solution is not beautiful, but it works. In HTML file I defined new DIV and before opening context menu I position it.

```
$("#contextDiv").css({
    position: "absolute",
    top: contextMenuTapY,
    left: contextMenuTapX
});
```

Then I open the context menu relatively to this DIV

HTML:

```
<a href="#popupElement" id="aPopupElement" data-position-to="#contextDiv" data-rel="popup"></a>
```

JS:

```
$("#aPopupElement").click();
```